# can mpdf use fpdi-pdf parser extension?

Tags: tcpdf, mpdf, fpdi

I've been working with mpdf in order to join pdf files and adding internal links to its pages. I was forced to add fpdi-pdf parser to handle pdf files > v 1.4. I'm having some issues to make them work together because they require class extension and I can't have a class extending both mpdf and fpdi-pdf parser.

There is an easier option to do this integration using tcpdf instead of mpdf, however it would be a pain to lose my entire work with mpdf.

Can you guys give me some advice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

mPDF v7 doesn't require class extending. Just install v1 of FPDI and the FPDI PDF-Parser and mPDF will use this under the hood.

FPDI v2 in mPDF is planned for mPDF v8.